# Compare multiple values in one condition

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
Int32 int1, int2, int3 = 123;
```

Given the above variables, how can I test that all of my variables have the value `123` without creating a collection to perform some `Any` or something on?

**What I've Tried**

```
if(int1 == int2 == int3 == 123)
{
   // Fantastic code here
}
```

**EDIT**

*I must apologise, I haven't been clear enough in my question. I'm fully aware of the `&&` operator, I was asking with regard to 'elegance', i.e. how can I avoid repeating the value I want to compare against.*

*In the same way I have assigned all 3 integer variables the same value in one hit, I'd like to now make the comparison. It's looking as though there is no way of doing this, so far. I think I'm asking the impossible, I'll have to stick to the basic syntax and keep it simple.*

Comment: Why are you disappointed? The type of `(int3 == 123)` is `bool` so when you try to compare it with `int2` you're trying to compare a `bool` with an `int` so the compilation error is expected.

Comment: @AmnonShochot - fair explanation, thanks. I was simply after a more concise way of testing multiple variables to the same value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an usefull extension function:

```
public static bool EqualsAll<T>(this T val, params T[] values)
{
    return values.All(v => v.Equals(val));
}
```

call it like:

```
bool res = 123.EqualsAll(int1,int2,int3);
```

Comment: The question explicitly says: "without creating a collection to perform some `Any`..."

Comment: And also wants to check *all*, not *any*.

Comment: The use of `&` operator looks interesting here. Can you explain what this is doing please? Thanks

Comment: Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much. Exactly what I'm after, I'll have a real explore of this to make sure there are no gotchas depending on what I'm evaluating. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd check edge cases on integers and what happens on negative numbers. But on the average positive number this should work.

Comment: The bitwise check is wrong. `(5 & 3 & 7) == 1`. It's not an "edge case", it's totally flawed.

Comment: @JayMee During your "real explore", make sure you check e.g. `int1 = 255`, `int2 = 251`, `int3 = 127`.

Comment: @Rawling - I've dropped the bitwise part since I thought there will be edge cases. Thanks for the investigation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, using the logical and operator:

```
if(int1 == 123 &&
   int2 == 123 &&
   int3 == 123)
{

}
```

Comment: Was fully aware of this syntax, you provided this answer because my question was unclear. Apologies. Upvoted anyway as it's technically correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(int1 == something && int2 == something && int3 == 123)
{
   // Fantastic code here
}
```

This is how you should do it using `&&` operator. You can check multiple conditions using this.

**UPDATE :**

As far as checking multiple values at one go is concerned, you can try making an array out those values and just fire a simple LINQ statement like this to check all of them for a particular value :

```
if (new[] { int1, int2, int3 }.All(x => x == 1))
```

Dont know if this fits into your requirement, just a suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(int1 == 123 && int2 == 123 && int3 == 123) {  // Code }
```

What your trying to achieve isn't possible the way you do it.
You have to separate it with &.

Comment: Same comment as what I've made on Christos' answer. +1.

Comment: You use: 

    private bool CompareValues(params int[] values) {